# Attempting to use uninitialized value when restoring the saved models

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to restore the saved model and do the testing.
However, I met the problem of `Attempting to use uninitialized value`. I've read some posts before. It seems I cannot do the global initialization. But the error seems interesting.

My code is:

```
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("trained_model_epoch-1.meta")
sess=tf.Session()
new_saver.restore(sess, './trained_model_epoch-1')
print('Test')
run_test_model(sess,y_out,...... split='Test', N=Ntest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `tf.train.Saver()` ?

```
building_graph_method()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, save_path)
```

Of course you would need to save your model, using saver

```
saver.save(sess, save_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are accessing your tensors/operations directly (if they are defined in the same script), rather than pulling them from the restored graph:

```
sess = tf.Session()
new_saver.restore(sess, './trained_model_epoch-1')
graph = sess.graph
w1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("w1:0")  # this tensor is initialized
w2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("w2:0")  # this tensor is initialized too
```